# Unable to get Var Output in DIV tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alterText(){
    document.getElementById('share_buttons').innerHTML = generateShareButton(url);
}


function generateShareButton(url) {
    url = encodeURIComponent(url);
    var title = encodeURIComponent(window.site.title + " - " + window.site.subtitle);
    var description = encodeURIComponent(window.site.description);
    var html = '<ul class="share-buttons">' +
            '<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + url + '&t=' + title + '" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Facebook</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=' + url + '&text=' + title + ':%20' + url + '" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Tweet</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + url + '" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Google+</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + url + '&description=' + description + '" target="_blank" title="Pin it"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Pin it</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '" target="_blank" title="Submit to Reddit"><i class="fa fa-reddit-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Submit to Reddit</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '&summary=' + description + '&source=' + url + '" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on LinkedIn</span></a></li>'
            + '<li><a href="mailto:?subject=' + title + '&body=' + description + ':%20' + url + '" target="_blank" title="Send email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Send email</span></a></li>'
            + '</ul>';
    return html;
}
</script>
```

Unable to get results in

```
<div id="share_buttons"></div>
```

Can I call it from some `.js` file? And if not, how to do it on page load? As I do not want to use `<body onload>` method...

Comment: you have to give the parameter ´url´ some value. and, also, is the function being called in any part of your code? here there is no call to the function.

Comment: I tried with    <body onload="javascript:alterText()">   but do not know howto call it properly.... which is themain issue

Comment: I removed the [tag:php] tag because this isn't a PHP question.

Comment: call the alterText() somewhere in script tag  and define url while giving it as a parameter. I am assuming you are written script tag at end of the page

Comment: if i would have knowledge of "how to give parameters"  then no need for experts plz help to correct code plz a i want to call  it from separate .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check fiddle here [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/e1yw945f/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/e1yw945f/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alterText();
});

function alterText(){    
    var url="http://url.com"
    document.getElementById('share_buttons').innerHTML = generateShareButton(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like charm...  How i can cal this function from some .js file

Comment: You can call *alterText();* from other js file also. just need to call like alterText();